# Is it acceptable for a user to have two answers to one question?

Tags: discussion

Is it acceptable for a user to post two separate answers to a single question? In which scenarios would that be acceptable?

If not acceptable; why does the functionality of TGO engine allows for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate to [When should I add another answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125751/when-should-i-add-another-answer)

Comment: ppl, I removed the polling-style answers in lieu of allowing a broader discussion on the topic. Everyone should be able to voice their thoughts on the issue rather than trying to drive a consensus by posting all sides of the conversation yourself. **[Polling is generally not a good substitute for discussion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Polling_is_not_a_substitute_for_discussion)** . Just a heads up. Thanks.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Sure. I don't think it prevents discussion but instead see it as a convenience for the voter. I'd assume that any well expressed answer would be voted up in place of those terse answers. But in the meantime, for me, it is an easy and accessible alternative to express my opinion for something I might not want to elaborate in details on (that is if I wasn't the OP/answerer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote directly from the accepted answer on Meta.StackExchange: [When should I add another answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125752/217110)

> You should rarely add another answer if you already have one answer to
> that question.
>
> .....
>
> You should not split one answer into multiple
> posts, even if it is a long answer consisting of several parts. If the
> parts together make up the answer, it should be one post. (But, if you
> write the awesomest answer ever and hit the post-length limit, go
> ahead and break the rule.)
>
> If you can offer substantially different answers to the problem, that
> can be a case where multiple separate answers are appropriate, but
> each should be able to stand by its own merits, of course. Variations
> of the same theme belong in the same post, making more than one answer
> of them just adds noise.
>
> Even if you suggest two unrelated ways to solve a problem, if they are
> short enough, they should usually be (separate) parts of one post,
> since more posts clutter the page. Unless they don't fit together. For
> example if one of them uses very controversial techniques, having them
> in the same post would make voting difficult. It would force people to
> a) upvote content they disapprove of, b) not upvote content they
> strongly approve of, c) downvote content they approve of, d) not
> downvote content they strongly disapprove of. Seems undesirable.
>
> If putting both ways into the same answer would create an unreasonably
> long post, and the two ways aren't related, you should post them as
> separate answers. Two normal-sized posts are easier to digest than one
> humongous.
>
> You should post multiple answers if they are unrelated and
>
> - they are too long to be in the same post or
> - they are superficially similar, so having them in the same answer    could be confusing or
> - they are so dissimilar that having them in the same answer would be    incongruent or
> - one of them is likely to meet objection and the other approval or you    really think it would be better to have them in different
>   posts.

so **yes it is acceptable** providing it meets the criteria above.